datajoint seems to require schemas to have the same values at shared *secondary* attributes
When trying to join two datajoint tables that have the same values for a primary attribute but different values for a shared secondary attribute ("sweep_key") I am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Cell In[199], line 1
dj_classes'PatchNeuron'*timepoints
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/datajoint/expression.py:259 in mul
return self.join(other)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/datajoint/expression.py:285 in join
assert_join_compatibility(self, other)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/datajoint/condition.py:71 in assert_join_compatibility
raise DataJointError(
DataJointError: Cannot join query expressions on dependent attribute sweep_key
I think this maybe the same issue as described here:
Does datajoint "join" operator require tables to have the same value at shared secondary attributes?
And subsequently said to be fixed here:
https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/pull/981
Has anyone run into this? Do you have advice or work arounds? The one listed on the original Stackoverflow post did not work for me.
Thanks so much!
Tried:
Work around  listed on previous post
@property
def key_source(self):
return PatchNeuron.proj() * PatchNeuronTimepoints
where PatchNeuron and PatchNeuronTimepoints are the two tables I'm trying to join.
When I remove the secondary attribute sweep_key, the tables join just fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
